Can't get serializer/normalizers to work properly after upgrading to 4.0 from 3.2.2
I have upgraded api-platform to 4.0 from 3.2.2 and now my serializers are messed up.
I use ld+json and followed the documentation and created a new serializer (and removed all other serializers just to debug/eliminate interference)
Without any normalizers, I have @id for each entity, resource,... in the response.
When I add this normalizer, only my DaySlots and TimeSlots have @id and all other endpoints missing @id in the response!
  App\Normalizer\SlotNormalizer:
    decorates: 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item'
    arguments: [ '@App\Normalizer\SlotNormalizer.inner' ]

    <?php
    
    namespace App\Normalizer;
    
    use App\ApiResource\DaySlot;
    use App\ApiResource\TimeSlot;
    use App\Service\SecurityService;
    use ArrayObject;
    use Exception;
    use InvalidArgumentException;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\ExceptionInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
    
    readonly class SlotNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface, SerializerAwareInterface
    {
        private DenormalizerInterface|NormalizerInterface $decorated;
    
        public function __construct(
            DenormalizerInterface|NormalizerInterface $decorated
        ) {
            if (!$decorated instanceof DenormalizerInterface) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                    sprintf('The decorated normalizer must implement the %s.', DenormalizerInterface::class),
                );
            }
    
            $this->decorated = $decorated;
        }
    
        /**
         * @throws ExceptionInterface
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function normalize(
            $object,
            $format = null,
            array $context = [],
        ): array|string|int|float|bool|ArrayObject|null {
            $data = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);
    
            $data['test'] = "Hi";
    
            return $data;
        }
    
        public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null, array $context = []): bool
        {
            return is_a($data, TimeSlot::class) || is_a($data, DaySlot::class);
        }
    
        public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null, array $context = []): bool
        {
            return $this->decorated->supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format, $context);
        }
    
        public function denormalize($data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = []): mixed
        {
            return $this->decorated->denormalize($data, $type, $format, $context);
        }
    
        public function setSerializer(SerializerInterface $serializer): void
        {
            if ($this->decorated instanceof SerializerAwareInterface) {
                $this->decorated->setSerializer($serializer);
            }
        }
    
        public function getSupportedTypes(?string $format): array
        {
            return [
                DaySlot::class => true,
                TimeSlot::class => true,
            ];
        }
    }

Also trying to get even denormalizer to work for patch request, but whatever I try I end up with de/normalizer not executing, throwing out of memory error, circucal reference error, or simply not being able to transform iri reference to entity in post/patch operations, meaning {"myRelationship": "/api/v1/entity/1"} does not become a entity and doctrine tries to persist a new empty entity.
Already dealing with this past 2 days, I am frustrated and angry.
Documentation is totally busted as well,
# api/config/services.yaml
services:
  'App\Serializer\ApiNormalizer':
    # By default .inner is passed as argument
    decorates: 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item'

"By default .inner is passed as argument" sorry but it **** doesn't! Without decorating it throws circucal reference error!

Try this code
<?php
namespace App\Normalizer;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\AsDecorator;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
#[AsDecorator('api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item')]
class AddOwnerGroupsNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
    public function __construct(private NormalizerInterface $normalizer)
    {
    }
    public function normalize(mixed $object, string $format = null, array $context = []): array|string|int|float|bool|\ArrayObject|null
    {
        dump('IT WORKS!');
        return $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);
    }
    public function supportsNormalization(mixed $data, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $this->normalizer->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }
}

From https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/normalizer-aware

if you read my post, i did the exact same thing, and it does not work correctly.
